# NDepend - how to extract comments from code?

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

Is it possible to somehow use CqLinq to extract for each method its comments header?

i.e.  ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jiri, no with NDepend you can only count the [number of lines of comment](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbLinesOfComment), not extract them.